# Why is sudo not working in org babel tramp?

Tags: org-mode, tramp, sudo

I have this code here. I also tried adding `sudo touch`. The only thing that
seems to work is if I run it as a normal bash org code and use the SUDO_ASKPASS
variable.

```
#+begin_src bash :results output :dir /sudo::
touch /root/file
#+end_src
```

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (excessive-lisp-nesting "1706")
  signal(excessive-lisp-nesting ("1706"))
  tramp-error((tramp-file-name "sudo" #("root" 0 4 (tramp-default t)) nil #("void" 0 4 (tramp-default t)) nil "" nil) excessive-lisp-nesting "1706")
  tramp-signal-hook-function(excessive-lisp-nesting (1706))
  tramp-file-name-unify((tramp-file-name "sudo" #("root" 0 4 (tramp-default t)) nil #("void" 0 4 (tramp-default t)) nil "" nil))
```

Comment: Your testcase works for me, so perhaps it is something related to your configuration. Can you reproduce it with `emacs -Q`? I recommend bisecting your config to figure out what setting conflicts.

Comment: It does look like it works with the exception of `No org-babel-execute function for bash`. Unfortunately I don't have a minimal config to try that has everything setup for org-babel. I "think" it was working a few days ago, perhaps it was the emacs update cause I know emacs updated recently.

Comment: You don't need much. This should do it: `emacs -Q --eval "(require 'ob-shell)" file.org`, where `file.org` is the Org mode file with the src block above in it. You'll need to confirm the src block evaluation but that's minor. In any case, your testcase works for me too (both with my standard config and also with `emacs -Q` as above), so I second @db48x's advice to bisect your config file.